# PHP Print all queries sent to MSSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm using `PDO` with the `sqlsrv` drivers. I would like to print out all queries passed through the connection that's initalised in `__construct`.

My setup is as followed;

```
public function __construct() {
    try{
        $this->connRead     = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=" . DB_SERVER . "; Database =" . DB_NAME, DB_USER_READ, DB_PASSWORD_READ);
        $this->connRead->setAttribute(  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){ echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
}
public function __destruct() { $this->connRead = null; $this->connWrite= null; }
```

I would then make a request/call as such;

```
$sSQL = "SELECT foo FROM Table"
$st = $this->connRead->prepare( $sSQL );
$st->execute();
```

On loading a page I would like to be able to print all queries that use `$this->connRead` in plain text to the browser. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soloution I found was to create a Class (DataHandler) to handle any DB calls. It gets initalised with a connection string from within the calling class or page.

Queries can then be peformed as such;
`$oDH->RunCommand($sSQL, [params])`

Because all the queries are sent through the `DataHandler`, I can log whatever I choose. i.e. execution time, all queries ran on page, bound params etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [debugDumpParams](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php), and that's all what PDO can provide for you.

You will receive statement and variables for this statement.

Moreover you can receive this info only for particular statement not for connection.

And there is no way to receive clear SQL, you can just receive something like:

```
SELECT :date AS `date`
```

And in case when your statement text will be too long - it will be truncated, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410151/why-pdo-debugdumpparams-truncate-query).

But all modern frameworks live with it...

Comment: thanks for the reference to `debugDumpParams` will come in useful. Shame there is nothing that can it there are collect the queries sent :(